# How to access the OAuth2AccessTokenResponse at the AuthenticationSuccessHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have currently implemented OAuth2 login sequence with Google and Discord. I have noticed that the `OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient` handles and processes the access token, refresh token and the openid token as expected (I have seen them while debugging).

However, at the end of the authorization process when it comes down the succeshandler, the tokens have disappeared. After doing some research it appears that `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` (spring-security source code) transforms the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken` (which holds the tokens) into a `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`. During this transformation the tokens become effectively lost.

What can I do to make the access token and refresh token available in the `Authentication` object in the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` method? Could I replace this filter somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I completely overlooked one detail:

The `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` puts the `OAuth2AutherizedClient` (with tokens) in the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`.

All you have to do at the success handler now is to get the client registration id of the provider, and voila:

```
    private void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response,
                                         Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

        OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication, request);

        // A happy guy with his access tokens and refresh tokens
    }
```